# Numpy inner product of 2 column vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vector, inner-product

How can I take an inner product of 2 column vectors in python's `numpy`

Below code does not work

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1], [2]])
np.inner(x, x)
```

It returned

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])`
```

instead of `5`

Comment: `np.inner` isn't used that often in `numpy`.  `np.dot` is much more common.  When looking a documentation, keep in mind that your column vectors are 2d arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inner product of a vector with dimensions 2x1 (2 rows, 1 column) with another vector of dimension 2x1 (2 rows, 1 column) is a matrix with dimensions 2x2 (2 rows, 2 columns). When you take the inner product of any tensor the inner most dimensions must match (which is 1 in this case) and the result is a tensor with the dimensions matching the outter, i.e.; a 2x1 * 1x2  = 2x2.

What you want to do is transpose both such that when you multiply the dimensions are 1x2 * 2x1 = 1x1.

More generally, multiplying anything with dimensions `NxM` by something with dimensions`MxK`, yields something with dimensions `NxK`. Note the inner dimensions must both be `M`. For more, [review your matrix multiplication rules](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/matrix/multiply-matrix.php)

The `np.inner` function will automatically transpose the second argument, thus when you pass in two 2x1, you get a 2x2, but if you pass in two 1x2 you will get a 1x1.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1], [2]])
np.inner(np.transpose(x), np.transpose(x))
```

or simply define your x as row vectors initially.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2])
np.inner(x, x)
```

Comment: `x = np.array([1, 2])` is what he meant I'm guessing.

Comment: @kabanus yes he probablydid but the question did state "column vectors" thus i wanted to give an answer which preserves the column vector

Comment: `transpose()` does not actually work in the above case because it still results in a 2d array. `flatten()` will do the job, as will `reshape(2)` (both yield a 1d array).

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean to have:

```
x= np.array([1,2])
```

in order to get 5 as output, your vector needs to be 1xN not Nx1 if you want to apply [np.inner](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html) on it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following it will work

```
np.dot(np.transpose(a),a))
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure col_vector has shape (N,1) where N is the number of elements

then simply sum one to one multiplication result

```
np.sum(col_vector*col_vector)
```